# onsubmit for zipcode text input. XMLhttprequest: input zip, return city

Tags: javascript, json, input, xmlhttprequest, onsubmit

I am trying to create a little program which involves taking zipcode input and obtaining the related city using http://www.zippopotam.us/. Eventually i will parse the city data and store as variable as the program is developed.. perhaps use the long/lat for more specific regions.

1. When using the below code, after an initial zipcode is entered, it works as planned and i see an alert with the intended JSON result. After the initial zip input, once the zip is changed and submitted again, it doesnt work. The updated zip is reflected in the URL but it disappears from the text input field and the **city** function is not executed. It takes a second submission for it to work. Why is this happening and how can i get around it?
2. is www.zippopotam.us/ a good way to go about this or are there better options?

.

```
<div id="location">
<form onsubmit="city()">
<input type="text" name="loc" id="loc" />
</form> 
</div>

function city(){
var zip = $('#loc').val();
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open("GET", "http://api.zippopotam.us/us/"+zip, true);
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(client.readyState == 4) {
    alert(client.responseText);
};
};

client.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are hitting a cross domain security policy, which means that a file coming from YOUR domain is not allowed to load data from ANOTHER domain.

Typically, you would make a request to your OWN server, which would query the zippopotam.us, and return the data to you. From a client perspective, it makes the data looks like it comes from your server, and the call is therefore allowed.

Alternatively, for a client side only solution, check if http://www.zippopotam.us/ supports jsonp: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP . There are other methods too (e.g. see if your provider has some allow-origin header).

Read this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At a closer look, I see the http response from the target server shows Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. I understand that the * means the resource can be accessed by any domain in a cross-site manner. I now have this working in firefox but not in safari. Not sure what browser difference is stopping safari working.